# How to connect to a remote slim server using fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I want to use my slim server remotely with fitnesse but it doesn’t work because the fitnesse always want start the slim server locally.
The problem:
On **hostA** there is a standalone fitnesse server (started from command prompt with „**java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8080**” command) with a very simple textfixture:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!define slim.host {hostB}
!define slim.port {8090}
!define slim.pool.size {2}

!|script|Count|
|count|
|count|
|check|counter|12|
|count|
|count|
|check|counter|4|
|count|
|count|
|check|counter|6|
```

On **hostB** I have a slim server which listens on port **8090**.
If I start the fixture I get the following error message:

**„Unable to start test system 'slim': java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java"": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified”**

It seems that fitnesse want to start the slim server anyway locally because if I define the test runner:

```
!define TEST_RUNNER {<path>/to/my/slimserver/mycslim.exe}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m}
```

It works but this is not the behavior what I need. I thought If I define the **slim.host** and **slim.port** fitnesse will connect to the **hostB** automatically without starting the slim server locally.

It is possible to configure the fitnesse server to connect to a remote slim server without starting it locally?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a custom TestSystem to achieve this. The key is the client builder.

```
public class CustomClientBuilder extends SlimClientBuilder {
   public CustomClientBuilder(Descriptor descriptor) {
      super(descriptor);
   }

   @Override
   public SlimCommandRunningClient build() throws IOException {
       Object commandRunner = new MockCommandRunner(this.getExecutionLogListener());
           return new SlimCommandRunningClient((CommandRunner)commandRunner, this.determineSlimHost(), this.getSlimPort(),
            this.determineTimeout(), this.getSlimVersion(), this.determineSSL(),
            this.determineHostSSLParameterClass());
   }
}
```

Use this client builder in your test system factory:

```
public class CustomTestSystemFactory implements TestSystemFactory {
  private final SlimTableFactory slimTableFactory;
  private final CustomComparatorRegistry customComparatorRegistry;

  public CustomTestSystemFactory(SlimTableFactory slimTableFactory,
        CustomComparatorRegistry customComparatorRegistry) {
    this.slimTableFactory = slimTableFactory;
    this.customComparatorRegistry = customComparatorRegistry;
  }

  public final TestSystem create(Descriptor descriptor) throws IOException {
    SlimClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CustomClientBuilder(descriptor);
    SlimCommandRunningClient slimClient = clientBuilder.build();
    HtmlSlimTestSystem testSystem = new HtmlSlimTestSystem(clientBuilder.getTestSystemName(),
        slimClient, this.slimTableFactory.copy(), this.customComparatorRegistry);
    return testSystem;
  }
}
```